# Python appends only one value

Tags: python, python-3.x, append

Here is my Python Code

```
pos = 0

for i in range(-10,10):
    x = 3*i + 1
    dataX = []

    #dataX.append(x)

    dataX.insert(pos,x)
    print("insert "+str(x)+" at "+ str(pos) + "|" + str(dataX))
    pos += 1

print(dataX)
```

Simply append should work right? but it does not, but so is insert..

Both returns same values as following..

```
insert 1.9 at 13|[1.9]
```

that is 13th iteration as shown, and yet it does not do either insert nor append which should have generated list of data

I have no idea I've tried append as shown but results in [1.9] even with previous data.

Comment: There is nothing being "returned" here, there is no function being defined and no function being called. It is not clear what you expect to happen, but I suspect the problem you are facing is caused by assigning a new list to `dataX` each iteration of the loop: i.e. `dataX = []`

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new `dataX` with every iteration of the loop. Put that *outside* the loop.

```
pos = 0
dataX = []

for i in range(-10,10):
    x = 3*i + 1
    # etc.
```

Answer (score -2):

For each iteration of the loop you recreate dataX. You should declare it before the loop.